# WPF ListBoxItem ControlTemplate breaks some MouseDown/Selection

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have an issue with `ListBoxItem`s. I am trying to make all controls in the `ListBoxItem` select it as well, so clicking on a `TextBox`, `Label`, etc will select the `ListBoxItem`. Pretty simple so far.

I am also changing the `ListBoxItem` Template to change the selection visualization from highlighting the background to just drawing a border. Also pretty simple.

The combination of these two, however, seems to cause some really irritating issues with `MouseDown` and `PreviewMouseDown`, specifically in my case regarding `Label`s in a `Grid`, where one creates a "void" occupied by `Grid` space.

Using snoop, I can see the `PreviewMouseDown` event stopping at the `ScrollViewer` inside the `ListBox`, and not going all the way to the `ListBoxItem`.

[image: click no worky]

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ListBoxClickThroughTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="525"
        Height="350">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                 SelectionMode="Single">

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Label Name="VerySuperLongLabel"
                               Grid.Row="0"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               Content="VerySuperLongLabel"
                               Padding="0" />

                        <TextBox Name="Textbox1"
                                 Grid.Row="0"
                                 Grid.Column="1"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                                 Text="Textbox1 Text" />


                        <Label Name="ShortLabel"
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               Content="ShortLabel"
                               Padding="0" />
                        <TextBox Name="Textbox2"
                                 Grid.Row="1"
                                 Grid.Column="1"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                                 Text="Textbox2 Text" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDown"
                                 Handler="ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseDown" />
                    <EventSetter Event="MouseDown"
                                 Handler="ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseDown" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                <Border x:Name="Bd"
                                        BorderThickness="1">
                                    <ContentPresenter />
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace ListBoxClickThroughTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            Items = new List<string>() { "1", "2" };
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public List<string> Items { get; set; }

        private void ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var listBoxItem = (ListBoxItem)sender;
            listBoxItem.IsSelected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

However, if I remove the `Template` setter, all is well. Is there some magic in the template I'm missing? I tried renaming the border to "Bd" as that was what the default template border was named, but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to get a border drawn when clicking in the whitespace to the right of the second list item?

Comment: @aaron, I am trying to select the `ListBoxItem` by clicking _anywhere_ inside it and show the selection via a border (like the top selected item in the screen shot). The code works everywhere except the void to the right of "ShortLabel".

Comment: Didn't know you could use Snoop to look at events!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you change the horizontal alignment of the labels from "Left" to "Stretch" this will fix the problem and keep the visual formatting the same.

Mousedown events only work in areas where elements exist. By having the labels at a "left" horizontal alignment, you are creating the "void" you mentioned, where no element exists at that level that can be clicked. To visually see the difference, try temporarily setting the background property of the label elements that are giving you problems, and you'll see the element doesn't extend all the way to the textbox.

Comment: Brilliant! This fixes a long running issue I've had in my project.

Comment: So simple. Thank you! I figured the `ListBoxItem` would get the `MouseDown` event in a situation like this where there's a void. Thanks again!

Comment: Any idea why the `ListBoxItem` is not receiving the event? I feel like this is a good solution, but it doesn't explain why this event seems to die at the `ScrollViewer`.

Comment: To further @DanielJohnson's comment, if I remove the `ContentTemplate` from the `ListBoxItem` while the `Label`'s horizontal alignment is still "Left", the `Border` is getting the event rather than the `ScrollViewer` and is properly selecting the `ListBoxItem`. What gives, WPF?